# Find non-sequenced pattern between two delimiters

Tags: python, regex, tags, unordered

I am trying to use REGEX in order to find out if a certain tag is found inside the source code of a website.

The tag definitely starts with "<link" and definitely ends with ">".
There are some strings that need to be found between these two delimiters in order to "succeed":

- 'rel="alternate"'
- 'media='
- 'max-width:'
- '640px'
- 'only screen'
- 'href='

Within the source code of a website this should match for example the following tag:

The problem is, that the elements within this tag can be in a different sequence like for example:

```
< link media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" rel="alternate" href="http://m.example.com/page-1">
```

or:

```
< link href="http://m.example.com/page-1" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" rel="alternate"/>
```

My problem is, that using a REGEX formula like

```
(<link ).*(rel=).*(media=).*(640px).*(href=).*(>)
```

would need rel, media, 640px and href to be in exactly this order, but it is also possible that the order is completely another way around.

What I did so far:

- searching through Stackoverflow (it was probably asked before - but I couldn't find the solution. The former asker probably did use very differents wording when describing)
- try building the formula on https://regex101.com (this way I came up with what I have so far)

Can anyone push me in the right direction please?
Thank you in advance to everyone!

Comment: I would recommend you to use an HTML parser, or try to see if any of the suggestions here > https://stackoverflow.com/a/7564061/1535270

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression to identify clauses beginning with a match of `< *link` and ending with a match of  `*>` that satisfy the stated requirements.

```
< *link(?=[^>\n]*\brel="alternate")(?=[^>\n]*\bmedia=)(?=[^>\n]+\bmax-width:)(?=[^>\n]+\b640px\b)(?=[^>\n]+\bonly[ -]screen\b)(?=[^>\n]*\bhref=)[^>\n]+ *>
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/tW9WEV/2/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
< *link             : match '<', 0+ spaces, 'link'
(?=                 : begin positive lookahead
  [^>\n]*           : match 0+ characters other than
                      '>' and line terminator
  \brel="alternate" : match 'rel="alternate" with a leading
                      word boundary 
)                   : end positive lookahead
(?=[^>\n]*\bmedia=)           : similar to above
(?=[^>\n]+\bmax-width:)       : similar to above
(?=[^>\n]+\b640px\b)          : similar to above
(?=[^>\n]+\bonly[ -]screen\b) : similar to above
(?=[^>\n]*\bhref=)            : similar to above
[^>\n]+ *>          : match 1+ characters other than '>'
                      and line terminator, followed by
                    : 0+ spaces, '>'
```

The six positive lookaheads can be in any order.

Comment: I was so long struggling to find exactly what you are suggesting. Thank you sooo much!!!
Will play with it tonight :-)

Comment: Couldn't get it completely running yet, but I think I could manage to make a few changes to get most if it work in the online testing tool on regex101.com:

(< *link *)(?=[^>\n]*\b(rel=\"alternate\"))(?=[^>\n]*\b(media=\"))(?=[^>\n]*\b(max-width))(?=[^>\n]*\b(640px))(?=[^>\n]*\b(href=\"))(?=[^>\n])(?=[^>\n]*)([^>\n]+ *>)

Just in my real python code it still says there is a syntax error (invalid syntax) right with the first < character in the formula.

Comment: I will keep on trying by myself - just wanted to give feedback how it goes so far.
Definetly Cary has helped me a lot to get where I am now. Thanks again.

I will post the final solution once I have it :-)

Comment: Try entering just `(< link *)([^>\n]+ *>)`to confirms that works. Then test each lookahead separately, e.g. `(< link *)(?=[^>\n]*\b(max-width))([^>\n]+ *>)`. btw, I don't see the value of the capture groups. They just tell you, for example, that the capture group `(max-width)` contains `"max-width"` if there's a match. I do see why you might be interested in capturing `"640"` in `(max-width: 640px)`, which is doable.

Comment: You might find it convenient to use the "Test String" section at regex101.com for saving parts or all of the regex you are testing.

Comment: The Code Generator section helped. It seems adding r" to the regex helped, although the comments state that this is only necessary for Python2.x and I am sure to run Python3. The full working line is 

regex = r"(< *link *)(?=[^>\n]*\b(rel=\"alternate\"))(?=[^>\n]*\b(media=\"))(?=[^>\n]*\b(max-width))(?=[^>\n]*\b(640px))(?=[^>\n]*\b(href=\"))(?=[^>\n])(?=[^>\n]*)([^>\n]+ *>)"